Integration tests with Rabbitmq and .NET?
I have a web api with .Net, this API calls another service using rabbitmq, for unit tests I dont have problems becaose I mock the service that make this call, but how can I mock or simulate it on my integration tests
PD: I need to mock it because the second service that is called with rabbitmq makes calls to external API
Integration test with rabbitmq

use testcontainers and rabbitmq management image
